# IntelliJ Idea Main Menu Bar Moved From Mac Menu Bar

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

My IntelliJ IDEA IDE is now showing the main menu (File , Edit , etc) in the window as in the Windows version. I would continue to like it in the Mac Menu Bar but I can't seem to figure out how to move it back. Deleting my config folder and resetting preferences didn't seem to help.
Here's a picture of what it looks like now:
[image: Menu Bar Moved]

Any idea on how to move the bar back to the default Mac area?

Comment: What Java version is used to run IntelliJ IDEA? Any customizations in Help | Edit Custom Properties? Usually it's done via `apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar` property which is set to `true` by default in `Info.plist`.

Comment: Oh thanks, adding `apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar = true` in my Custom Properties file and restarting fixed it!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make sure you have `apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true` in `Help` | **Edit Custom Properties**. It should be already set to `true` by default.

Also check that IntelliJ IDEA is [running on the default JetBrains Runtime](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544879).

Comment: Or set to false so the menu will appear on the application window as in Windows (not fancy but works) 
Credits: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000444084/comments/115000371130

Comment: This was working for me, but no longer works as of IntelliJ 2020.1

Comment: *Update:* This solution started working again after I switched to the Jetbrains bundled JRE.

Comment: @bischoje, where did you check and change the JRE? I've just updated to 2020.1 and I'm having the same problem.

Comment: *Update:* Found it - Cmd + Shift + A, search and choose for "Choose Runtime…", then click "Use Default" in the popup. JetBrains article: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under Once I did this, I didn't need any custom properties or VM settings.

Answer (score 5):

Edit Custom Properties solution didn't work for me, the following did work:

- press the combination CMD+SHIFT+A
- type "vmoptions"
- Edit Custom VM Options
- add "-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=false" to the end of .vmoptions file
- press the combination CMD+SHIFT+A, type "restart", Restart, Just Restart

Answer (score 4):

I have been having the same issue with macOS Catalina, 10.15.4 and Intellij 2020.1 version. I had changed the intellij runtime to java 8 and that looks like it caused the issue. Changing the runtime to intellij default fixed the issue for me.

This is what I did, punch <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, Type "choose runtime" and then click on the `Use Default` button.

Comment: Thank you Jason for the formatting. Appreciate, i am new here and learning the ropes .

Comment: There is no choose runtime option

Answer (score 2):

You can also install Java 6 from Apple. Not sure if you need to uninstall previous versions first. I did just to be on the safe side. Reinstalled the newer JDKs after and it still works.

Answer (score 2):

Just adding one line '-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=false' to idea.vmoptions file.
It works for me. Please have a try[image: .]

Answer (score 0):

High Sierra now prevents you from Installing Legacy Java for OS X. "A newer version is installed" but it's still not compatible with IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: You can still reinstall it after removing or renaming /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework from recovery mode. I had to do this after installing 10.13.1 beta 3. Also, the latest IntelliJ EAP build seems to work without the legacy java 6. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JRE-434

Answer (score 0):

You can try: File -> Manage IDE Settings -> Restore Default Settings...

This helped me, although I needed to reinstall missing plugins (like Flutter)

Answer (score 0):

1. Press: Ctrl + Shift + A
2. Select: Actions
   3 Type: main menu clik ON